# Modernizr causing errors in IE8 (exception handling?)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, modernizr

I'm getting an error on one of my sites using Modernizr 2.6.2 in Internet Explorer 8.  It seems like IE <=8 freaks out if an exception is thrown but not caught, so it gets to this line and completely fails:

```
    if (typeof target != "function") {
        throw new TypeError();
    }
```

The error is: "Exception thrown and not caught"

If this was the result of me performing a Modernizr.something() call, I could surround that in a try/catch block to fix the error, but it's only 149 lines into my un-minified Modernizr build, and short of altering the source it doesn't look like I can catch the exception...is this true?

Anybody else having this issue?  I couldn't find it documented anywhere.  Any suggestions?

Comment: That is ... kind of the point of exceptions.  If they aren't caught, they bubble all the way to the top and bring the JS execution to a halt.  The *real* fix is to make sure that `target` is a function in whatever calls it.

Comment: Jeremy, yeah I understand the source of the problem (that target is not a function) and that the exception should be caught.  But it seems like to do that I need to edit Modernizr source, which I don't want to do unless necessary.  Is there any way to catch global exceptions thrown?